# jQuery - setInterval on mouseleave and clearInterval on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, function, setinterval, mouseleave, clearinterval

I'm trying dynamically to add some `DIVS` (*with dynamically added function*) to the `CONTAINER`. When I click on someone of these `DIVs` , `MENU` is inserted to this `DIV`.
On `mouseleave` I need to remove `MENU` from this `DIV` with `delay`  or `setInterval` about 5 seconds. It works, but chaotically... So I need :

1. When `mouseleave` out of this `DIV` and then immediately I put mouse
   back over this `DIV`, I need to stop `delay`  or `setInterval`.  I need to stop 
   removing the `MENU`.
2. There is some problem with function `'handler'`. Becouse when I add
   some `DIV` to `CONTAINER`, for the first time I need to use
   `doubleclik`, to call this function. But I need to use simple click.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/84nVQ/5/

HTML

```
<div id="add" style="background:yellow; width:100px;"> add new </div>
<div id="container"> </div>
<div id="menu" style="color:red;"><b> I'm here </b></div>
```

jQuery

```
function handler() {
    $(this).on({
        click: function(e) {
            clearTimeout(time);
            if ($(this).find("#menu").length) {
                return;
            }
            $('#menu').prependTo($(this));
            $("#menu").css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: "100px"
            }).show();
        }
    });
    $(this).on({
        mouseleave: function(e) {
            time = setTimeout(function() {
                $('#menu').appendTo('body').clearTimeout(time);;
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
    $(this).on({
        mouseover: function(e) {
            clearTimeout(time);
        }
    });
}

$("#add").on({
    click: function(e) {
       var timestamp = Date.now();
       var posx = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
       var posy = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
       $('#container').append(function() {
        return $('<div class="add_to_this" id="' + timestamp + '" style="left:'+posx+'px; top:'+posy+'px; ">Click here</div>').click(handler);
       });
    }
});
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background: palegoldenrod;
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    left: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.add_to_this {
    background:yellowgreen;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function handler() {
    $(this).on({...
```

what is `$(this)` ?

you are not using or passing any selector

use   `$("#container").on`

Comment: $('#container').append(function() {
        return $('<div class="add_to_this" id="' + timestamp + '" style="left:'+posx+'px; top:'+posy+'px; ">Click here</div>').click(handler);       });

Comment: how to add this function dinamically ?

Comment: OK. I found it. Thank you, for your attention. I'm not so good in english, so it took me longer time to understand what you ment... thx again.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution :

JsFiddle - working example : http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/84nVQ/6/

jQuery

```
function handler1() {
    clearTimeout(time);
    if ($(this).find("#menu").length) {
        return;
    }
    $('#menu').prependTo($(this));
    $("#menu").css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: "100px"
    }).show();
}

function handler2() {
    time = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#menu').appendTo('body').clearTimeout(time);;
    }, 5000);
}

function handler3() {
    clearTimeout(time);
}


$("#add").on({
    click: function(e) {
        var timestamp = Date.now();
        var posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
        var posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
        $('#container').append(function() {
            return $('<div class="add_to_this" id="' + timestamp + '" style="left:' + posx + 'px; top:' + posy + 'px; ">Click here</div>').click(handler1).mouseleave(handler2).mouseenter(handler3);
        });
    }
});
```